# Append and Remove to check if the text is in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, append

The nth comment get removed and the nth username is checked in other comments, and if the nth username is not in all comments(nth comment is already removed) it will be passed/appended in warn_usernames and afterward, the nth comment gets again added in the comments. Cycle continues

```
usernames = ["a", "b", "c"]
warn_usernames = []
comments = [["b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "b"]]

n = 0
while n < len(usernames):
    commente = comments[n]
    print(commente)
    usernamee = usernames[n]
    print(usernamee)
    comments.pop(n)
    if str(usernamee) not in str(comments):
       warn_usernames.append(usernamee)
    comments.insert(n, commente)
    n = n + 1
print(warn_usernames)
```

result I get

```
[]
```

result I expect to get

```
[c]
```

Thanks in advance, and I hope you got my question.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Part of the problem is that you repeatedly write about "comments" but they do not seem to be Python comments or English comments. Please clarify what a "comment" is.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Comments is just a list

Comment: @RoryDaulton done

Comment: `usernames` is an array of strings, but `comments` is an array of arrays of strings, not an array of strings. Therefore the line `if str(usernamee) not in str(comments)` will not work. You would need to iterate through the arrays of `comments`.

Comment: Also, I am finding it quite difficult to understand what the code is meant to achieve.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, it did help me somewhat...

Comment: @RajasRasam Great. I’ll keep thinking!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
usernames = ["a", "b", "c"]
warn_usernames = []
comments = [["b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "b"]]
# use a loop for with enumerate on usernames to get a username and its index
for n, username in enumerate(usernames):
    #loop on all others comments than the nth
    for comments_to_check in comments[:n]+comments[n+1:]:
        #check the username is in comments_to_check and 
        if username not in comments_to_check:
            # append to warn_usernames if not
            warn_usernames.append(username)
            # stop the loop on comments to go to the next loop on usernames
            # to prevent multiple time the same username to be appened
            break 
print warn_usernames
```

You'll get your expected output